# What is the purpose of a requesting a non existent resource

Tags: web-application

nwolb.com the site for Natwest Online Banking (a UK based bank) makes two requests to non existent resources.  For example:

[image]

https://82.13.77.77:4531/NonExistentImage20297.gif
https://127.0.0.1:4817/NonExistentImage25060.gif

What is the purpose of this?  Is it some kind of webapp security hardening?  It seems the port numbers and image numbers change but the ip addresses (external and loopback) do not.

Comment: I don't want to post an answer as I am not sure about this, but in theory, this may be to check for MITM attacker that intercepts all connections. It is possible such MITM attacker would unknowingly accept the connection before checking the pictures actually exist, so he would reveal himeslf.

Comment: It [appears](https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/strange-links-from-my-banking-website.361064/) capital one [does this](https://www.webpagetest.org/forums/archive/index.php?thread-12837-1.html) too

Comment: From the source it looks like it has more to do with fingerprinting than anything

Comment: @PeterHarmann I think that sounds like a plausible explanation. There has also been some malware that has used a similar technique to identify if they are being run in a protected environment typically used by researchers. If a request to a known non-existing resource returns, then you know that the environment is not as expected.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald can you give an example of that using something from the source?  I would be fascinated to know.  Thanks for taking the time to post originally.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that this is probably not web app hardening but instead per this forum post

https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/strange-links-from-my-banking-website.361064/

Is probably

"... just plain visitor tracking evilness..."

> Did this happen to be from a capitalone.com domain? I happened to see
>   a blocked script from 127.0.0.1 plus my public IP in my NoScript
>   listing. This kind of freaked me out, since (of course) it was our
>   credit card site.
>
> I did some digging, and that appears to come from an 'fp_AA.js' script
>   located at:
>
> https://login1.capitalone.com/resources/jscript/fp_AA.js
>
> I de-minified that script, and posted it here:
>
> http://pastebin.com/P3WiGzDG
>
> The relevant code calling the image is at line 509:
>
> ProxyCollector.doAjax = function (k, l) { var j =
>   document.location.protocol + "//" + k + ":" + getRandomPort() +
>   "/NonExistentImage" + getRandomPort() + ".gif";
>
> So, it appears to be some kind of browser fingerprinting/proxy
>   collector JavaScript. Perhaps it's trying to do an nmap-style TCP
>   fingerprint of the response when it sends an HTTP request to a closed
>   port?
>
> Also interesting is that I'm seeing those UUIDs listed on line 459
>   mentioned at:
>
> http://www.browserleaks.com/javascript
>
> And there's an interesting read from Mozilla about browser
>   fingerprinting at:
>
> https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting
>
> It doesn't appear to be malware, just plain visitor tracking evilness.

Comment: Can you give more information so this answer does not become obsolete if the link dies?